# Symfony 2 Redirect to url without www

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I don't know how to redirect my symfony application from:
http://www.mysymfonyapp.com
to:
http://mysymfonyapp.com

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
#    RewriteBase /
#</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /mysymfonyapp.com/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I'm entering application without 'www' it works, but with 'www' it has redirects loop. I've tried asking google, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out and answering for others.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysymfonyapp\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mysymfonyapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteBase /mysymfonyapp.com/web/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysymfonyapp\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://mysymfonyapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #RewriteBase /mysymfonyapp.com/web/ (you don't need declare RewriteBase if you have this code in mysymfonyapp/web/.htaccess)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L] #Remember to redirect app.php
</IfModule>
```